# How to get only successful responseText with Axum and Ajax

Tags: ajax, rust, rust-axum

In my web application, there are many situations where I use Ajax on client side and Axum on server side to handle Ajax calls. I want to return `String` when a function succeeds on server side, and I want to redirect a user to an error page immediately using `return Err(Redirect::to("/error-page"));` when a function fails on server side. So the function's Result is like `Result<String, Redirect>`.

However, this works only when the function succeeds. When the function succeeds, I can get the string value as a `responseText` and use it however I want on client side. That's great, but the problem arises when the function fails and I try to redirect the user to `/error-page` immediately using `return Err(Redirect::to("/error-page"));`

When a call from client side is just a normal form, I can redirect a user to `/error-page` immediately using `return Err(Redirect::to("/error-page"));`. However, when a call from client side involves Ajax, it won't redirect the user to `/error-page`, and instead it will show the whole raw html of `error-page.html` on my web site, which means the whole raw html of `error-page.html` was passed to the client side as `responseText`.

I want to simply redirect a user to the error page when an error occurs. How can I use Axum and Ajax together to stop returning `responseText` when there is an error.

Comment: The short answer is: don't use a redirect as a response to an AJAX call, because there isn't a standard way for XMLHttpRequest to tell you that a redirect happened. Return some other kind of response, like a 200 with a JSON payload that communicates the redirect to your JS application.